# C++ pass a pointer to an array of unknown size and the function sizes and fills it

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm sure there are a number of ways to solve this but I can't seem to find one. This is to get an idea of what I'd like to do:

```
void FillArray(_bstr_t *ptrArray)
{
    ptrArray = new _bstr_t[100];

    ptrArray[0] = "dfasef";
    .
    .
    .

}


int main()
{
    _bstr_t *ptrArray;

    FillArray(ptrArray)

    printf("%s", ptrArray[4]);
}
```

Comment: Please read up on references and also std;;vector

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, use a reference, note the extra `&`

```
void FillArray(_bstr_t *&ptrArray)
{
    ptrArray = new _bstr_t[100];
    ptrArray[0] = "dfasef";
}
```

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks